# Why does pandas categorical DataFrame give truth value error?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My data contains a column 'Married' having categorical values Yes or No. I changed this to numerical type:

```
 train['Married']=train['Married'].astype('category')
 train['Married'].cat.categories=[0,1]
```

Now I'm using following code to fill in missing values:

```
train['Married']=train['Married'].fillna(train['Married'].mode())
```

It's giving the error:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: Can you break up the computation to see if this error is due to the `.mode()`, `.fillna()` or `=` attribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that you are using logical operators such as `not, and, or` from base python on a numpy array or pandas series:

For instance:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,2,2])
not pd.isnull(s.mode())
```

gives the same error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

If you look at the stack trace, the error comes from this line:

```
fillna(self, value, method, limit)
   1465         else:
   1466 
-> 1467             if not isnull(value) and value not in self.categories:
   1468                 raise ValueError("fill value must be in categories")
   1469
```

So it is checking if the value you are trying to fill is in the categories; and this line requires the value to be a scalar in order to be compatible with `not` and `and`; however, `series.mode()` always return a series, which fails this line, try extracting the value from `mode()` and fill it:

```
train['Married']=train['Married'].fillna(train['Married'].mode().iloc[0])
```

---

A working example:

```
s = pd.Series(["YES", "NO", "YES", "YES", None])    
s1 = s.astype('category')
s1.cat.categories = [0, 1]

s1
#0    1.0
#1    0.0
#2    1.0
#3    1.0
#4    NaN
#dtype: category
#Categories (2, int64): [0, 1]

s1.fillna(s1.mode().iloc[0])
#0    1
#1    0
#2    1
#3    1
#4    1
#dtype: category
#Categories (2, int64): [0, 1]
```